# Web API ModelBinders - how to bind one property of your object differently

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have the following action signature

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostParam(Param param)
```

With Param looking something like this:

```
public class Param {
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Choices { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the hitch - what comes over the wire is something like this

```
{
  Id: 2,
  Name: "blah",
  Choices: [
    {
      foo: "bar"
    },
    {
      blah: "blo"
      something: 123
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want "Choices" to deserialize - I want it stored as a string (yes, I understand the security implications). Understandably, I get an error because since the default binder does not know this.

Now with Asp Mvc creating a specific ModelBinder would be fairly simple. I'd

- inherit DefaultModelBinder
- override the property deserialization with my own
- set the binder in my `Application_Start` using `Binders.Add`

Seems like with Web Api this is a different process - the System.Web.DefaultModelBinder doesn't have anything to override and that I can't hook things up using `Binders.Add`.  I've tried looking around but couldn't find much on how to actually do what I want. This is further complicated since apparently the ModelBinders api changed quite a bit over Beta and RTM so there's a lot of outdated information out there.

Comment: Can't you change your client to send the `Choices` array already serializes as a string to your Web.API method? So `{
  Id: 2,
  Name: "blah",
  Choices: "[ { foo: \"bar\" }, { blah: \"blo\" something: 123  } ]"
}`

Comment: @nemesv - I would prefer to not do any pre-processing on the client. I don't want to force all api consumers to worry about my server implementation.

Comment: Do you plan to support XML clients or JSON is enough? Because if XML is not needed you can change your `Choices` property to use `JArray` `public JArray Choices { get; set; }`

Comment: @nemesv JSON is sufficient and it's really unlikely to be more than one client to be honest. Really there's a dozen different ways to hack around the issue, but I'm looking for specifically how to do this with ModelBinders (or if that's not the right tool for the job then why and what is).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Web API you have to distinguish three concepts - `ModelBinding`, `Formatters` and `ParameterBinding`. That is quite confusing to people moving from/used to MVC, where we only talk about `ModelBinding`.

`ModelBinding`, contrary to MVC, is responsible only for pulling data out of URI. Formatters deal with reading the body, and `ParameterBinding` (`HttpParameterBinding`) encompasses both of the former concepts.

`ParameterBinding` is really only useful when you want to revolutionize the whole mechanism (i.e. allow two objects to be bound from body, implement MVC-style binding and so on) - for simpler tasks modifying binders (for URI specific data) or formatters (for body data) is almost always more than enough.

Anyway, to the point - what you want to achieve can very easily be done with a custom `JSON.NET` converter (JSON.NET is the default serialization library behind Web API JSON formatting engine).

All you need to do is:

```
public class Param
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomArrayConverter))]
    public string Choices { get; set; }
}
```

And then add the converter:

```
internal class CustomArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, JArray.Parse(value as string));
    }
}
```

In this case we are telling JSON.NET in the converter to store `Choices` as `string` (in the read method), and when you return the `Param` object with the `Choices` property to the client (in the write method) we take the `string` and serialize to an `array` so that the output JSON looks identical to the input one.

You can test it now like this:

```
    public Param PostParam(Param param)
    {
        return param;
    }
```

And verify that the data coming in is like you wished, and the data coming out is identical to the original JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this globally without adding attributes? I.e. register somehow a converter which will always apply for a property of a certain type. My use case is trying to convert properties of type (mongo) ObjectId. I added a ModelBinder (implementing IModelBinder) and this works for controller methods having direct parameters of type ObjectId, but for methods having parameters complex types which in turn have properties of type ObjectId it doesn't.

Comment: @adrianhara: did you ever figure this one out? Having to specify the attribute everywhere is annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't and yes it's annoying. Hopefully someone will answer here with a better solution.