# ModelBinder and sub models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I use in some models a sub model class (UserInfo) which should contain some user related info. This sub model can be used in various models, For example

```
public class Model
{
     int string Value { get; set; }
     public UserInfo User { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a model binder and registered it in WebApiConfig

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(UserInfo), new UserModelBinder());
```

The thing is the UserModelBinder isn't called by the WebApi processing pipeline. It seems that these modelbinders aren't called for the sub models. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question [What is the equivalent of MVC's DefaultModelBinder in ASP.net Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705794/what-is-the-equivalent-of-mvcs-defaultmodelbinder-in-asp-net-web-api/14706108#14706108) for some detail on where your bindings are going to be happening.

I suspect though that your `Model` is being passed in the message body?

If it is then WebApi will use a formatter to deserialise your types and process the model, the defaults being `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`, `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` or `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`.

If you are posting the model in the body then depending on your requested or accepted content-type is (application/xml, application/json etc) you may need to customise the serialiser settings or wrap or implement your own `MediaTypeFormatter`.

If you are using application/json then you can use `JsonConverters` to customise the serialisation of your UserInfo class. There is an example of this here [Web API ModelBinders - how to bind one property of your object differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653211/web-api-modelbinders-how-to-bind-one-property-of-your-object-differently/14698930#14698930) and here [WebApi Json.NET custom date handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856853/webapi-json-net-custom-date-handling)

```
internal class UserInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeOf(UserInfo);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
                                JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **HttpConfigurationExtensions.BindParameter** method register that the
>   given parameter type on an Action is to be bound using the model
>   binder.

so what you did is similar to:

```
void Action([ModelBinder(UserModelBinder)] UserInfo info)
```

It works only if action parameter is of specified type (UserInfo).

Try putting model binder declaration on UserInfo class itself, so that it's global:

```
[ModelBinder(UserModelBinder)] public class UserInfo { }
```

However, there are some differences in the way how WebAPI and MVC bind parameters. Here is Mike Stall's detailed [explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx).