# Model mapping between JavaScript client and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model

I have a case where the JavaScript client side model does not match with the WebAPI model. In the following code, the **status** on the client side is a **string** while the same in the WebAPI is an **integer**.

How can I achieve the mapping of *status from string to an integer* without adding an **if** statement in the Post method and without modifying the **Order** model?

```
$.post('/Shipping/UpdateStatus', { orderId: 1000, status: "Accepted"} )

void Post([FromBody] Order order)
{
}

class Order
{
    int OderId { get; set; }
    int ShippingStatus { get; set; };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom JSON.NET converter to achieve this. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698930/4972749) for detailed information. For more information regarding this topic see [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

```
class Order
{
    int OderId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomIntConverter))]
    int ShippingStatus { get; set; };
}
```